# Vue app - Firebase deploy database issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-functions

I successfully deployed my Vue app using Firebase hosting except for one small thing - the database that I was running from localhost isn't appearing / being referenced when I navigate to the hosting URL (https://.firebaseapp.com.

Instead, any changes I make in attempt to recreate the data on the hosted site only effects my instance running on localhost!

Basically:

- Why am I not seeing any db data once i deploy using the standard firebase commands `firebase init` and `firebase deploy`?
- When I deploy how can I use the same database from localhost but have it running as a copy so that the deployed database and localhost database are kept separate?

Answer (score 0):

- I answered the first part via changing how I was deploying. Screenshot is attached.[image]
- I answered the second part through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591525/different-environments-on-firebase-web-application)